# mysql Select names for counts from different tables

Tags: mysql

I have 1 table with ID's as column names and another table that is mapping those ID's to descriptions. 
What I'm looking for now is to have a query that is giving counts for several of those columns and displaying the description from the other table that is matching the column name of table 1

Table1:

```
A01 | A02 | A03 | A04 | B01 | B02 | C01 | C02 | C03 | etc.
```

Table2:

```
ColumnID | Description
```

Query to get the counts;

```
Select count(A01), count(A02), count(A03), count(A04) from Table1;
```

The result will have column names of 'count(A01)', but instead I would like to have the description of Table2 instead.

any suggestions?

Comment: Schema and queries you tried. Without it we can't help.

Comment: You can have that using sub-queries and joins. But without the structure of your DB/Schema we can't help you.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to get columns of *Table1* from **INFORMATION_SCHEMA**  database:

```
SELECT `COLUMN_NAME`, `Description` FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS 
INNER JOIN `Table2` ON `COLUMN_NAME`=`ColumnID`
WHERE`TABLE_SCHEMA`='{your_database}' AND `TABLE_NAME`='Table1'
```

Remember to change **{your_database}** and table names you want to use, and this query will give you the columns from *Table1* and their descriptions stored in *Table2*